# Is there a word for answering a question with a question?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I am aware that answering student questions with further, leading questions is sometimes dubbed “Socratic,” but I am asking more broadly about all occasions where someone asks a question and, instead of an answer, receives another question in response. Has a word ever been coined to name this phenomenon?

Comment: Someone wrote to Ann Landers, asking why Jews always answer a question with another question.  Landers, born Esther Friedman, replied, "Why not?"

Comment: A more idiomatic say it might be to use the phrase "Let me answer that by asking you this."  See [Brian Regan - Standing Up - Part 3](http://www.ebaumsworld.com/video/watch/751168/), at time 6:50.

Comment: "[Asinine](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1078&bih=967&q=asinine&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&gs_rfai=)"

Comment: Have you read *Rosencrantz and Guildenstern are dead,* by Tom Stoppard, specifically the scenes where they play the game of [*Questions*](http://www.ralentz.com/old/misc/humor/game-of-questions.html)?

Comment: I don't know, what do you think ?

Comment: I have learned that the only way to fully understand a mans struggle is to walk a mile in his shoes; so sometime the only way to have someone fully understand the answer to a question is to see the question through the eyes of someone who has found the answer. Wisdom cannot be taught but only learned.

Answer (score 25):

This method of answering questions with questions, in order to let the questioner realize that he can find the answer by reasoning (Socrates would say that the answer was in him all along), is called ***maieutics*** (the related adjective being *maieutic*).

Comment: Oh, very nice! Just what I was hoping for: a real word, not a hyphenated coinage. Let me ponder for a few hours, though, about whether this nice word is satisfactory, or whether its semantic range is a bit too narrow; sometimes people answer a question with another question not because they believe in the other person's innate wisdom, but because they want to evade a straight answer, or even to violently challenge the premises — or right — of the questioner to ask the question. It would be nice to have a word that also covered more strident reasons for answering a question with a question.

Comment: It's worth noting that the word is derived from the Greek root maia, meaning _midwife_.

Comment: @senderle: and as such, the only other English word I can find that shares this root is *May* :)

Answer (score 11):

Such a question can be called a **counter-question**, but I do not believe there is an English word for actually posing such a question.  You could make one up, such as "counter-questioning".  That should be understood, at least.

Comment: Counter-question is on the OED (attested from 1864), and Wiktionary.

Answer (score 4):

Is it not true that ***counter-question*** is a good match that describes the exact structure that you inquire about? Can you have a counter-question without an initial question?

Also, wouldn't you agree, though it might be obvious, that the second question (the answering question) is called a [rhetorical question](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/R/rhetorical%20questions.htm)?

Out of numerous figures that are are related to this type of address, if I use for example [interrogatio](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/I/interrogatio.htm) and question my own answer, preferably with more style than I employ, am I not actually *confirming* and *reinforcing* the answer that I have given?

Other figures are: [erotema, anacoenosis, anthypophora, dianoea, aporia, epiplexis, exuscitatio, pysma and ratiocinatio](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/R/rhetorical%20questions.htm) and some of them cover exactly the meaning that you mention in comments: challenging the initial question.

In case that the second question is *not* a rhetorical question, but a real question that is raised by the first question then I would say you are simply investigating the subject in search for [stasis](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Canons/Invention/Stasis.htm) (and the term counter-question still covers it).